# Python: PyParsing Module Parse Exception

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am fairly new to python but previously had a log parser working, which is now giving me issues! A sample of the log I am trying to parse is:

```
Oct 18 00:00:37
```

I have defined the initial parse objects as follows:

```
   #Define Parse objects
    Month=pyp.Regex(r"([a-zA-Z]{,10})")           #up to 10 letters: lowercase a-z or uppercase A-Z
    Day_Of_Month=(".")        #(r"(\d\d)"         #digit, digit
```

As shown above, I had tried `(r"(\d\d)"` as the day of month object, but after errors tried to make it even more generic. Regardless of trying different variations and some searching around I still get the error below.

Error Message:

```
"pyparsing.ParseException: Expected ".", found '1'  (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)"
```

No doubt this is likely an obvious oversight, but I can't figure it out. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you meant `Day_of_month = pyp.Regex(r".{1,2}")`? Or you could also try using pyparsing's classes that abstract away the `re` arcana and use `pyp.Word(pyp.nums)`, which would be equivalent to a regex of the form `\d+`, but a little more readable.

Comment: I am an idiot. I did indeed forget to include pyp.Regex...! apologies. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll add one more comment, before this question gets closed because it is solved by fixing a typo. Using `pyp.Regex(".")` will match any single character, which feels pretty inviting to mistaken parsing depending on what you get in the future. Also a regex of "." will only match one character, you'll probably want ".+", ".{1,2}" or "\d+" to be more specific to just accepting 1 or 2 numeric digits, instead of just *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

PaulMcG answered my Q. I simply forgot to add pyp.regex